# Why PDF Processing Error, even though PDF is saved without any error?

Tags: python, python-requests, pypdf

I have to download the file from this url using python.

```
https://icms.bombinoexp.in/ImageHandler.ashx?ID=37997&Type=BOE&FileExt=.pdf
```

Here's my code:

```
response = requests.get(url)
open('pdf_file.pdf','wb').write(response.content)
```

File is downloaded successfully and i can open it using the Adobe and can see the contents, but when I'm processing this file using `PyPDF2`, it is giving

```
PyPDF2.utils.PdfReadError: EOF marker not found
```

I had one PDF file and it was processed smoothly with `PyPDF2`, and when I cross-checked both files, I can see new PDF file has extra information.

Also, if you click the above PDF link, it will be opened in `Chrome PDF Viewer`, if you click save button and then open the PDF file in `sublime` or any other editor, you can see the extra data. But If I save this file with printer option and instead of printing, If I `Save as PDF`, it is saved successfully and also processed successfully. I'm unable to understand the difference, can anyone please point me in right direction?

Comment: requests `get` doesn't save your file to disk. Don't know where the pdf_file.pdf is coming from, but not from the get().

Comment: if you see the code, i'm opening a pdf file and saving request.content in the file.

Comment: You requesting something, but you don't save it to a file.

Comment: `open('pdf_file.pdf','wb').write(response.content)`. this line of code is saving response.contents in the file.